# Java heap size exception

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, heap-memory

After running 24 hr of my java program it shows exception like this "Exception in thread 1 Out of Memory Error Java  Heap Size" , in my code i am using collection objects like hashmap, array list , vector and all.

This Problem is coming in the section of my code where i'm taking 500 data creating 500( in my db table 90000 data) HashMap at a time & setting this hashmap object into the ArrayList> in finally block i'm setting hashmap object null and passing this arralist object to another method for processing .This is continuing till the 90000 data.

For doing this processing program i'm using thread & from run() method of thread giving while condition true & calling dataprocessing method.

Comment: Also you can try running visualvm tool shipped with Java to get an idea on excessive objects retained on heap. Also you can profile other aspects like threads, CPU etc.

Comment: Looks like a memory leak, please check your code that it is not holding too much references over the time. Increasing the heap size is not a real fix for that, it will only delay it for a couple of more houres.

Comment: hey when i'm clearing my collection object then it saves null value in  database .

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial to analyze memory leaks using visualvm http://rejeev.blogspot.in/2009/04/analyzing-memory-leak-in-java.html

Comment: Rather then describing what your code does, post the [relevant parts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means your heap is full. You have too many and/or heavy objects in memory.

Possible causes:

1. you keep references to unused objects, and create too many of them

    **Solution:** check for memory leaks
2. you actually need all those references, but your heap is too small

    **Solution:** increase the heap

Since your exception happens after a long time, I believe the first one is probably your problem.